# Overriding Standard 'NEW' button using Visualforce or Creating custom button and replace standard button

Tags: visualforce, button-overrides, default-value, standard-field

Using a Before trigger/ Workflow has not helped me fill in or provide a default value to a standard field(NAME) while saving a new record.

I was asked to build a Visual force page and then override the 'NEW' button to add a default value to the token field, type Name, which will then allow to save a record.

Visual force page code used to override 'NEW':

```
<apex:page standardController="Certification__c"
action="{!URLFOR($Action.Certification__c.New, NULL, ['Name'='DoNotEdit'], true)}"/>
```

My 'NEW' button before overriding:
[image: before]

My 'NEW' button after overriding.
[image: after]

My Contact look-up field value tends to disappear after i override the new button page. Token is the standard field, type Name. My 'Cancel' button is also not working after the override.

How can i bring everything from the default page, but only add a default value to the token(Name) field.

**UPDATE - explained further**

```
 Field Label = Token, Field Type = Name, Data Type = Text(80), Indexed, required (cannot be empty)
```

Name field is required in order to save the record, hence a before trigger won't work here. Name type fields don't take default values and is always a required/mandatory field. So the field Token is a 'text' field which goes like contact.Name, account.Name etc..(goes by .Name) This type of field requires a value upon saving. you cannot also provide a default value. I tried using a workflow, or a before trigger. But these work only after the record is saved but not just before it is saved. I want my user to not input this token every time they create a new record, but pull the value from it's parent object field.

SOLVED:
As Brian suggests below, I created a new button. You can use this link [URL Hacks](https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-url-hacking-tutorial/)
My final button URL looks as follows (note always have the retURL or return url) :

```
/a09/e?CF00NE0000004Nt36={!Contact.Name}&CF00NE0000004Nt36_lkid={!Contact.Id}&Name={!Contact.C_Token__c}&retURL=/{!Contact.Id}
```

Comment: I believe you need to explore all the `URLFOR` parameters and options.  You should be able to set the Contact ID as a parameter in the `URLFOR`, as well as a return URL when you press the cancel button.

Comment: Is it possible to clone the existing standard page, and then do the edit's in it

Comment: I think you can if you use the Web Link option and do some URL hacks there (see [here](https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-url-hacking-tutorial/) for a sample or just google "button url hacks salesforce").  I'm still not clear on the question - what's the main objective?  A trigger might still be useful depending on the end result you're looking for

Comment: BTW, if you're moving to Lightning, or using Chatter Actions is an option, [here is a great post](https://www.salesforceben.com/migrate-your-salesforce-url-hacks-to-actions/) for prepopulating values

Comment: I have explained further, please check my update. hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to prepopulate fields on the UI when the user tries to insert a new record:

1. **In Classic** - try using the Web Link option in the new button override option and do some URL hacks as explained [here](https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-url-hacking-tutorial/)
2. **In Lightning** (or Classic using Chatter Actions) - you can use Actions to prepopulate fields and that can be your main entry into inserting a new record.  There's a great post on that [here](https://www.salesforceben.com/migrate-your-salesforce-url-hacks-to-actions/)

---

If you're just trying to set the SObject.Name field, this can be achieved through a before trigger.

Here's a sample if you wanted to set the Opportunity Name to "{Account Name} - {Amount}" anytime the Opportunity was created or updated (i.e. it'll always overwrite the user's attempt to change the name):

```
trigger MyOppTrigger on Opportunity(before insert, before update) {
    for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new)
        opp.Name = opp.Account.Name + ' - ' + opp.Amount;
}
```

Note that if you're trying to pull some other value from the `Account` lookup field, you'll need to do a separate query to grab that other field, or use a formula field to pull that lookup field's value to the opportunity.  Then the `opp.Name` code would look like this:

```
opp.Name = opp.Cust_Field_on_Account__c + ' - ' + opp.Amount;
```

At this point, might as well just add the whole logic into the formula field and just do `opp.Name = opp.Opp_Auto_Name_Formula_Field__c`

Comment: .Name field is required in order to save the record, hence a before trigger won't work here. Name type fields don't take default values and is always a required/mandatory field. I have mentioned this issue in my previous **Update**, please have a look

Comment: Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data. Token 
Error: You must enter a value

Comment: A `before` trigger actually runs before the record hits the database - hence setting the Name to a real string value should work.

As for Invalid Data error - that error sounds like you're not assigning a value to `Name` - meaning whatever you're assigning to it might be empty or null.

Comment: I'm trying to assign a value to this field through the trigger. But when clicking NEW and then SAVE, this required field is left blank. Meaning I want it to retrieve a value from another place and set it to this field before saving the record. Meaning this field is left blank. I can't assign a default value nor set it as 'Not-required'

Comment: Got it.  Again, look at my original comments about the links for URL hacks, or moving them into Actions and using prepopulated values

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm trying out the URL hacks, please restructure your answer so I can mark it as correct, i will edit my question too

Comment: Take a look now.  I kept both answers just in case people find it useful

Comment: Looks good, thanks a lot your ideas worked.